# Not able to get a list of documents from Firebase Subcollection Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application where I need to have 3 heirarchy for email folders and notes like this: [image: Diagram]
Now I'm not able to get the list of documents under the **folder** collection.

I have tried this till now:

```
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('user')
    .doc(widget.email)
    .collection('folder2');
await collection.get().then((snap) {
  data = snap.size;
  print(data);
});
```

But this is just giving me 0 in the console, but showing all the entries for the notes collection so what should I do?

Comment: I think snap.length is going to work. 

snap.forEach(docsSnap=> {
            let doc = docsSnap.data();
 });

Comment: It doesn't even print when I write it like that.  `snap.docs.forEach((element) {
        data = element.data();
        print('caced $data');
      });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did get all the documents in the folder level by simply adding a few fields in that Collection like name, description etc.
Though I still don't see a way to get all the documents containing subcollections without adding any fields.
[image: Newly Created Design]

Answer (score 0):

**try using the length of the documents retrieved in the result.**

```
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('user')
    .doc(widget.email)
    .collection('folder2');
await collection.get().then((snap) {
  data = snap.docs.length;
  print(data);
});
```

Comment: It is still giving out 0

Comment: check the names of collections and documents once. in the image your first collection is users but in the query its the user.

Comment: This is working for me `var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(widget.email).collection('folder').doc('16').collection('notes');` See here all the names are the same but this is showing me all the data in the notes collection but when I only write it until the folder part it just shows 0

Comment: please check the above comment has folder collection and in the question, it's folder2. both are different collections.

Comment: See I have checked these things for over two days now but wasn't able to get the solution which is why I'm asking it over here. What I am saying is correct I have folder and folder2 both the folders but only when I add **.doc(folder_name).collection('notes')** I get the data in my console but not when I'm trying to access the **folder** or **folder2** collection.